# QML: как зарегистрировать typedef-псевдоним простого типа C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

Пусть в коде C++ имеется объявление:

```
typedef quint32 Index;
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE int item (Index i) const;
};
```

При попытке вызвать item из QML возникает ошибка: неизвестный тип Index. Добавление после объявления Index `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (Index)` вызывает ошибку: повторное добавление типа unsigned. Как в таком случае сообщить QML о том, что Index -- псевдоним целого типа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quint32 уже зарегистрирован с именем quint32, зарегистрировать его с другим именем уже нельзя (даже использовать std::uint32_t не получится, если его реальный тип совпадает с quint32). Так что единственное решение - не использовать свои псевдонимы для используемых в QML типов.

Причина такого ограничения по большей части в том, что при регистрации типа его имя запоминается ровно в том виде, в котором оно передано в макрос, т.к. другого переносимого способа получения имени типа в виде строки времени выполнения просто нет.  Точнее, разработчики boost::typeindex нашли способ, но это всё-равно от компилятора зависит.

Comment: Спасибо большое!